# Who to declare plugins for update kuzzle V1 to kuzzle V2

Tags: plugins, upgrade, kuzzle

I currently use version 1 of kuzzle and i will be using version 2.
I have a problem because i have overloaded the back part with a plugin (declared in the enabled folder in V1). However in v2 i do not see where to declare the plugins. I are successful in loading it into the docker but when launching kuzzle it is not taken into account.

I have use this : "bash -c "$(curl https://get.kuzzle.io)"" to install kuzzle V2.

If I can be more explicit in my request:
Where should we declare a plugin so that it is taken into account when launching kuzzle? In version 1 of kuzzle it was enough to declare the plugins in an "enabled" folder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Since Kuzzle v2, the code is very similar to a classic Node.js Framework.

First you need to create an `app.ts` file and instantiate the application inside. (I will use Typescript in this example but it also works with plain Javascript)

```
import { Backend } from 'kuzzle';

const app = new Backend('my-application');

app.start();
```

In Kuzzle v1 (but also in v2), plugins are defined as a class. You can use `require` to load that class, instantiate it and then tell the framework to use the plugin:

```
const myPlugin: any = require('./my/plugin/dir');

app.plugin.use(myPlugin);
```

You can use the [kourou app:scaffold](https://github.com/kuzzleio/kourou/#kourou-appscaffold-name) command to create an empty Kuzzle v2 application. Then just add your Kuzzle v1 plugin directory and load it from the `app.ts` file.

Additional links:

- [Write an Application for Kuzzle v2](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/getting-started/write-application/)
- [Use a plugin in an Application](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/develop-on-kuzzle/external-plugins/)